# How to separate common components from index/app chunk using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2, code-splitting

I am new to webpack and have a few questions which I am still not clear after reading the docs.

1. If we define multiple entry point chunks, do we need to declare all of them with script tag in my index.html and load them on site load? **Is there a way to load an entry point chunk runtime and not of site load?**
2. Say, I have 2 entry chunks: vendor and index. As part of code splitting, the app (index chunk) is further code splitted using react routes. However, I see 2 issues

   - I still see some react components present in multiple chunks (say, 1.js and 4.js). I want to separate them into a common chunk. I tried using CommonChunksPlugin and the following code, but I still dont see it happening.

`new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['index'],
         minChunks: 2,     }),`

**How can I ensure all the code splitted chunks are unique and don't have common React components?**

- In the main index.js entry chunk I see some code which I don't think is required to be loaded on site-load.

**How can I separate individual react components to a child chunk and load dynamically without defining a separate react route?**

Any help/example to understand these 2 issues will be greatly helpful.

Thanks in advance.